# Problems converting an NSString to a double value

Tags: ios

I cannot understand why I am getting the results below, any help will be appreciated.

```
NSString  *amountString =@"9,376.41";
double  amount = [amountString doubleValue];
NSLog(@"My Amount %f",amount);
My Amount 9.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with converting numbers to and from strings you should always use a correctly configured `NSNumberFormatter`

```
NSString *amountString = @"9,376.41";

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSNumber *amount = [formatter numberFromString:amountString];
NSLog(@"My Amount %@", amount);
```

You can set the locale/format to handle different thousands separators etc

Comment: Yes beware of locale. I know in some places 35,631 is thirty five point six three one not thirty five thousand six hundred and thirty one

Answer (score 1):

take out the comma by using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString and it would work

```
NSString  *amountString =@"9,568,376.41";
NSString *outString = [amountString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
double  amount = [outString doubleValue];
NSLog(@"My Amount %f",amount);
My Amount 9568376.410000
```